# How can I programmatically configure compiler for CMake via Python on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, icc

I have a python build script I'm using to build a number of projects that are configured via CMake on windows.  Previously, we used MSVC to build these projects, and everything was fine.  I want to try to incorporate ICC into the build now, via these python scripts.  I can choose the native compiler directly in the UI if necessary, but I'd rather do everything programmatically.

Problem is, it's failing with either syntax errors, or just not paying attention to the cmake options.

I can set:

```
"CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE 2013/bin/intel64/icl.exe",
"CMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH":"C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE 2013/bin/intel64/icl.exe"
```

And that's part of a `cmakeItems` array that's then fed into the generation:

```
generate(x86Generator, cmakeItems, osName, buildTarget)
```

where the other options are set via command line switches (for `x86generator` and `buildTarget`) or by default (ie, `osName` is detected in the script itself).

Before trying anything, I'm running this from a command line prompt where I've run

```
iclvars intel64
```

in the icc bin directory to ensure that all of the icc variables are properly configured, and I can type `icl` on the command line and confirm that it's in the path.

Running the above means that the C compiler remains the default msvc compiler.

I've also tried running:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_INIT icl)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_INIT icl)
```

but that's giving me a syntax error on the icl portion.  I thought that maybe it's a path issue, but doing:

```
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_INIT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2013\bin\intel64\icl")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_INIT "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Composer XE 2013\bin\intel64\icl")
```

is also giving me a syntax error.

So how can I programmatically set the C/CXX compiler from a python script calling cmake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

ICC does not work with CMake on Windows, so don't bother.

http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=6929

Much better to run it with some form of visual studio compiler and then mess about with icprojconverter:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/ICProjConvert100

Answer (score 0):

On the command line you specify the compiler via the environment variables `CC` and `CXX`. I'ld guess you need to properly prepare the envornment of the cmake command and you should not change CMakeLists.txt internals.

E.g.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('CC=%s CXX=%s cmake ../path/to/src' %('icc','icpc'))
```

Comment: Does this work on windows?  Most of the solutions via environment variables seem to be geared to linux/unix.

Comment: on windows it should be `"set CC=%s && set CXX=%s && cmake .."`

Comment: This is not working for me; the CMakeCache.txt does not contain the CMAKE_C_COMPILER option when run this way, but it does if I explicitly set the compiler via the UI.  I'm using 
  `os.system("set CC=\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE 2013/bin/intel64/icl.exe\" && set CXX=\"C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Composer XE 2013/bin/intel64/icl.exe\" && cmake -G " + cmakeGenerator + " ../../gdcm")`

Comment: It also doesn't work if I do `set CC=icl && set CXX=icl && build.py`, in the hopes that that would set the environment variables for the python execution.